# Среднее количество массивов

Tags: javascript, html

Вот код из 3 чисел массивов определяется среднее арифметическое. Кто знает как сделать чтоб количество чисел массивов можно было задавать самому, а не 3 как на примере?

```
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tmp.css" />
  -->
<style type="text/css">
  label {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ww() {
    var oi = document.getElementById('fld').getElementsByTagName('input');
    var val = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < oi.length; i++) {
      val += +oi[i].value;
    };
    val = val/oi.length;
    document.getElementById('d').value = val;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <p>Среднее арифметическое</p>
    <div id='fld'>
      <label>x1=<input type="text" id='a' size='4'></label>
      <label>x2=<input type="text" id='b' size='4'></label>
      <label>x3=<input type="text" id='c' size='4'></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Нажми" onclick="try{ ww() } catch(e){alert(e)}">
   </div>
   <label>y=<input type="text" id='d' size='4'></label>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить ещё одну функцию для добавления поля:

```
function addInput() {
    var inputs=$('#fld').find('input');
    var itemNumber = inputs.length + 1;
    $('#fld').append('<label>x'+ itemNumber +'=<input type="text" id="input'+ itemNumber +'" size="4" /></label>');
}
```

А в html добавить кнопку, чтобы это поле добавлять:

```
<input type="button" value="Добавь" onclick="try{ addInput() } catch(e) {alert(e)}" />
```

[Вот что](http://jsfiddle.net/uvbqhckd/1/) получится в итоге.

PS.

1. Если подгружаете в проект jquery, то используйте его по полной, особенно для селекторов.
2. Инпуты лучше закрывать в html, то есть писать так: `<input type="text" />`